# Customizing Apache Logs

Tags: apache, logging, customization

I am running a website with siginup/login process. and I like to insert user ids when the user signs up or in to my website.
My apache access.log is as in the following:

```
115.137.10.87 - - [26/Aug/2013:07:38:52 +0900] "GET /api/game/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1402 "-" "android-async-http/1.4.3 (http://loopj.com/android-async-http)"
115.137.10.87 - - [26/Aug/2013:07:38:59 +0900] "GET /api/premium/brand HTTP/1.1" 200 721 "-" "android-async-http/1.4.3 (http://loopj.com/android-async-http)"
115.137.10.87 - - [26/Aug/2013:07:38:59 +0900] "GET /api/brand/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2510 "-" "android-async-http/1.4.3 (http://loopj.com/android-async-http)"
115.137.10.87 - - [26/Aug/2013:07:39:00 +0900] "GET /api/game/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1402 "-" "android-async-http/1.4.3 (http://loopj.com/android-async-http)"
```

I can clearly see what http request was sent from what ip address. 
But if I put the user id (eg. $userid) to this log, it would be wonderful log, and I will be able to get a good statistic information for making decision.

If it is possible, is there any way to do this?
Any advice will be really appreciated.

The log will be like this:

```
115.137.10.87 - - [26/Aug/2013:07:38:52 +0900] "***[USERID]*** GET /api/game/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1402 "-" "android-async-http/1.4.3 (http://loopj.com/android-async-http)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using HTTP Basic or Digest authentication, then the user name is derived from an HTTP header and can be inserted into the log by using `%u` in a `LogFormat` directive in your apache config.  If you have a login system that does not include the username in a header (likely), then the only other option I know of would be to somehow set an environment variable which Apache could then write out with `%{FOOBAR}e`.  See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html

Otherwise, you're probably better off writing out your own log file from your application code (or use an application level logging library - Log4j, or whatever.)

Comment: Thanks so much for quick reply. It would be a great help.

Comment: I read the article of apache log. but I don't know where to set my own variable and use it. Can't find a sample code. Can you give me an example? I am worried that my stupid try will cause any problem with the system.

Comment: Is your login using HTTP Basic or Digest authentication?  In order to use %u, it needs to be.  Otherwise, these are your main options for setting environment variables: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html